# How to find and remove part of word in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm new into vim, I have hug text file as follow:

```
ZK792.6,ZK792.6(let-60),cel-miR-62(18),0.239
UTR3,IV:11688688-11688716,0.0670782
ZC449.3b,ZC449.3(ZC449.3),cel-miR-62(18),0.514
UTR3,X:5020692-5020720,0.355907
```

First, I would like to get delete all rows with even numbers (2,4,6...).

Second, I would like to remove *(18)* from entire file. as a example:
cel-miR-62(18) would be cel-miR-62.

Third: How can I get delete all parentheses including it's inside? 
Would someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to delete *every second line* (line numbers 2, 4, 6, ...), or all lines that *contain* an even number?

Comment: lines numbers 2,4,6.., Maybe you can help with the third one.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one:

```
:g/[02468]\>/d
```

where `:g` matches all lines by the regex between the slashes and runs `d` (delete line) on the matching lines. The regex is quite easy to read, the only interesting symbol there is perhaps the `\>`, which matches end of a word.

For the second question:

```
:%s/\V(18)//g
```

where `%` is the specification meaning "all lines of the file", `s` is the substitute command, `\V` sets the "very nomagic" mode of regexes (not sure what your default is, you might not need this) and the final `g` makes vim substitute all occurrences on each line (with an empty string, the one between slashes). Make sure that `:set gdefault?` prints `nogdefault` (the default setting of `gdefault`), otherwise, drop the final `g` from the substitute command.

Answer (score 1):

1. To remove every even line (or every other line):

```
:g/^/+d
```

2. To remove every instance of (18):

```
:%s/(18)//g
```

3. Remove all the parenthetical content:

```
:%s/(.\\{-})//g
```

Note: the pattern in third answer is a non-greedy match.